# Dynamically add/delete rows

Tags: javascript, spring, jstl, el

I have a table, following is my code:

```
<table id="div1" style="display:none">
        <tr><td>Host Name</td><td>Directory</td><td>User Name</td><td>Password</td></tr>
        <c:if test="${empty location.fEvents}">
        <tr><td><form:input path="userEnteredHostNameString" size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
            <td><form:input path="userEnteredDirectoryString" size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
            <td><form:input path="userEnteredUserNameString" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
            <td><form:input path="userEnteredPasswordString" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
        </tr>
        </c:if>
            <c:forEach items="${location.fEvents}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
                <tr><td><form:input path="fEvents[${loop.index}].hostName" size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
                <td><form:input path="fEvents[${loop.index}].directory" size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
                <td><form:input path="fEvents[${loop.index}].userName" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
                <td><form:input path="fEvents[${loop.index}].password" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td></tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
```

whatever this `${location.fEvents}` comes to either empty or with values..if User wants...user can add/delete a row and the values of the row should save back in the database..

what is the best way to do it..can we do it in `spring` or we need to use `javascript`..suggestions are really appreciated

EDITED: How can add validation errors to these fields if they are empty or null(just to the above code without javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with both Spring and JavaScript. But if the data is supposed to change on the backend, you need to make JavaScript do XHR requests. Google "JavaScript AJAX".

About validation:
If your validation is not critical (i.e. only a convenience) you can do it client-side.

If your validation is "critical", you should first implement it on the server, and then when it works perfectly you can implement a simpler version for the client so they don't have to reload as much. Using GWT you can share the validation code.

Comment: how can we do that with spring..just some hint will be useful

Comment: validation is not that critical..I will go with client side..thank you

Comment: @srinathveda: read [this](http://maxheapsize.com/2010/07/20/spring-3-mvc-ajax-and-jquery-magic-or-better-simplicity/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673656/how-to-use-ajax-jquery-in-spring-web-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

For validation on server side for the fields you can refer the following post by me. Its kind of similar to your question. Please refere [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614718/how-to-validate-dynamically-generated-fields-server-side) question and answer by me.

Hope this helps you. Cheers

Comment: Great to know that. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it really helped you. :)